# How to populate an an objectId inside an array of objects in mongoose aggregate pipeline?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a two mongoose schema with the following structure.

```
const ImageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      image: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Media',
        default: null,
      },
      caption: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
      },
      credit: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        default: null,
      }
})

const NewsStorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ...,
  images: [ImageSchema]
  ...,
})
```

In one of the my api endpoints I have used mongoose aggregation. In it, I have successfully used `$lookup` stage to populate other foreign fields in `NewsStory` model. But I am unable to figure out how to populate the each `image` and `credit` inside `images` since it is an objectId inside an object, inside an array. Actual data looks something like this.

```
{
  images: [
    {
      image: "507f191e810c19729de860ea",
      caption: "A Rainny Day",
      credit: "707f191e810c19729de860eb"
    },

    {
      image: "607f191e810c19729de860ea",
      caption: "Sweet Delight",
      credit: "827f191e810c19729de860ns"
    }
  ]
}
```

How may I populate the `image` and `credit` using the `$lookup` stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the magic word to your problem whould be $unwind.

it should look likely like this:

```
{ '$unwind': '$images' },
{ '$lookup':
        { 
            from: 'Media',
            localField: 'images._id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'images.image' } },
{ '$unwind': '$images' },
{ '$lookup':
        { 
            from: 'User',
            localField: 'images._id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'images.user' } },
```

And then you have to group your data.

How to use it is very good explained in this issue:

[Mongoose.aggregate(pipeline) link multiple collections using $unwind, $lookup, $group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64180625/mongoose-aggregatepipeline-link-multiple-collections-using-unwind-lookup)